# "from way back" as an adverbial

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbial-phrases

How is "from way back" used **as an adverbial**? Can it be used in a present-tense sentence? The following is an example sentence of "from way back" in the OED. Is it natural in contemporary English? If not, how does contemporary English differ from earlier English as regards "from way back"?

> I dined and wined and toasted him **from way back**.

Here's the OED definition:

> Long ago. from way back: from long ago; since long ago; (in extended use) through and through.

Comment: That's a usage citation from 1870, that seems to be translated from Virgil's original Latin "poem" (but it's "peculiar" in many ways; the preceding sentence is ***He don't exhibit one redeeming feature***). So it was probably a bit unusual even when it was written. The *next* two citations are Mark Twain 1889 / 1892 where ***I tell you, he's an artist from way back!*** would be perfectly ordinary English even today. Basically, nothing much has changed.

Comment: ...and as you probably know, this exact issue has been extensively covered by [thegrammarexchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/from-way-back-as-an-adverbial?reply=706710675492316872) a little while ago.

Comment: The Mark Twain example illustrates the adjectival usage. I'm interested in the **adverbial usage**.

Comment: Imho, this is the definitive takeaway from thegrammarexchange... *The fact is that [**from way back**] is inescapably somewhat informal, no matter what the sentence, and informal expressions are known for not being good targets of prescriptivistic grammatical rigidity. If that's what you want, **you're barking up the wrong tree.***

Comment: That comment is irrelevant as it doesn't describe what rule underlies the adverbial usage, except from it being informal.

Comment: Good luck with it, then. I think *you're barking up the wrong tree* is a good position to take here.

Comment: That sounds like a "There's nothing we can do about it," dismissive attitude that won't further our understanding of "from way back."

Comment: ...but if someone who knows Latin would be good enough to give us a detailed explanation of exactly what the original for that 1875 citation means, I'd be interested. I have no idea what it means, even with [the full context.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+dined+and+wined+and+toasted+him+from+way+back%22)

Comment: -1 for lack of research and details. Look up examples in a good online dictionary, google the expression and you'll see how the expression is commonly used. **1.** “Listen, I **know** folks in that neighborhood **from way back.**“ **2**. “This painting **has been** in the family **from way back**” **3**. "We **know** the Smiths **from way back.**" **4**. She **was** an old girlfriend of his **from way back** and was on particularly friendly terms with his parents

Comment: ["from way back"](https://fraze.it/n_search.jsp?q=%22from+way+back%22&l=0&t=0&ffo=false&findid=-1&ff=)

Comment: Your example 4 is irrelevant because "from way back" is an adjectival there. Numbers  1 and 3 are common enough in that "know... from way back" is commonly used to describe interpersonal relationships.

Comment: But still, there's a remaining issue as the adverbial doesn't seem to freely occur with verbs. For example, I was told that "He understands from way back that it's hard to master English" is unaceptable.

Comment: And "he knows from way back how to bake cakes" is not okay either.

Comment: The loose translation from Virgil found by FumbleFingers is obviously written in a jokey, vey colloquial (and mid-Victorian) style. Presumably the intended meaning is "I have been regularly entertaining him to dinner for a very long time".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It's a *very* colloquial translation in 19th century American slang:  ["**Got up a supper**, fed his **lousy crew**,](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_Free_and_Independent_Translation_of_th/PH1hw_HBZCAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22got+up+a+supper,+fed+his+lousy+crew.%22+%22You+talk+about+obeying+Jove%27s+decree+Flapdoodle%22&pg=PA21-IA1&printsec=frontcover) And heard his egotistic yarn **clear through**! You talk about obeying Jove's decree, **Flapdoodle!** […] But **if the gods are worth a nickel**, I hope they'll give you an eternal **pickle**!“

Comment: @KateBunting Would you say, "I regularly entertained him to dinner from way back"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you really find “This painting has been in the family from way back”  okay? A twenty-something American told me he would have instead phrased the sentence as "This painting has been in the family for a long time."

Comment: "From way back" is "slang", very informal, but acceptable in casual speech. You should not use it in an essay.

Comment: @Apollyon - No, I certainly wouldn't say it - that's why I stressed that the style was old-fashioned and colloquial, and _guessed_ the meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think the expression's informality is the reason why the American wouldn't phrase the sentence that way. After all, he is a man in his early 20s and supposed to be open to lots of informal language. And "from way back" is not a recently invented slangy expression.